# Bootstrap-sass gem Javascript not Working in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

when using the bootstrap-sass gem i have loaded my css files properly, however have been receiving an error when i try loading the javascript files. I have followed the procedure of loading javascript from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass however when I view my webpage on localhost

## I receive the error "couldn't find file 'bootstrap'"

This is what my application.js file looks like - Any help would be much appreciated!

 **Application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
// Loads all Bootstrap javascripts
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by removing gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0' out of the assets group in gemfile! YAY

Answer (score 3):

From the *Rails 4* the [`:assets` group isn't used anymore](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-gemfile), please remove the group from **Gemfile**:

> Rails 4.0 removed the assets group from Gemfile. You'd need to remove that line from your Gemfile when upgrading. You should also update your application file (in config/application.rb):
>
> > Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

Answer (score 0):

Did you `bundle install` and make sure you are loading `application.js` (from the assets pipeline).

Comment: How do you make sure you are loading application.js from the assets pipeline?

Comment: Let us say in Rails 4 if you are using `application.html.erb` as layout, if it contains something like `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true` then you can be sure that it is included.

Comment: in that case it is included. Do you know what else it could be?

Comment: I got it to work by removing gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0' out of the assets group in gemfile! YAY