# Installing bootstrap with Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've added the following to Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

I added this to assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss (renamed to .scss):

```
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
```

I then ran `bundle install`.

I've added this controller: `rails g controller firstpage index`.  When I visit localhost:3000/firstpage/index, I get this error:

> Showing /Users/myuser/Projects/test5/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5
>   raised:
>
> File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
>
> @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
>    @import "bootstrap";

Anyone know what I did wrong?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902692/rails-bootstrap-setup/34007339#34007339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you restart your server when you bundle install.  Also, remove `*= require_self` and `*= require_tree .` when using imports.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted the server? `CTRL + C` and then `rails s` again.